# Not losing vector names when going for ListVector to array in rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I have a regression result and I want to convert the `lm_results` into python objects that I can work with. If I do:

```
print(lm_results.rx('coeftable'))
```

I can see the coefficient's name in $coefficients. But if instead I want the Python array of coefficients and do

```
lm_results.rx2('coeftable')
```

then I get the array with coefficients but I lose the information about the coefficient names.

I'm limited to using version `3.5.1`. With the current version, I can simply do:

```
with (ro.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter).context():
    coef_table = ro.conversion.get_conversion().rpy2py(result.rx2('coeftable'))
```

To get the desired result.